# korn shell script failing

Tags: linux, unix, sh

Need help with below korn shell. The statement `if (( ${lista[expr $FNO + 5]} == $MM ));` is failing with syntax error. Getting syntax error for ==. Tried -eq too but same issue.

This returns nothing: `${lista[expr $FNO + 5]}`. 
How to get the month value here?

```
#!/bin/ksh
# get a list of files and dates from ftp and remove files older than ndays

ftpsite="xxx.com"
ftpuser="ftpuser"
ftppass="ftppwd"
putdir="/ftpdir"

MM=`TZ=GMT+29 date +%b`
DD=`TZ=GMT+29 date +%d`

 echo removing files older than $MM $DD

 # get directory listing from remote source
 listing=`ftp -i -n $ftpsite <<EOMYF 
  user $ftpuser $ftppass
  binary
  cd $putdir
  ls -l
 quit
 EOMYF`


 lista=$listing


 # loop over our files
 FNO=0
 while (( $FNO < ${#lista[@]} )); do 

  # month (element 5), day (element 6) and filename (element 8)
  #echo Date ${lista[`expr $FNO+5`]} ${lista[`expr $FNO+6`]}          File: ${lista[`expr $FNO+8`]}

  # check the date stamp

  if (( "${lista[`expr $FNO + 5`]}" == $MM ));
  then
if (("${lista[`expr $FNO + 6`]}" -lt $DD ));
    then
     # Remove this file
  echo "Removing ${lista[`expr $FNO + 8`]}"
     echo "Removing ${lista[`expr $FNO + 8`]}" 

      ftp -i -n $ftpsite <<EOMYF2
      user $ftpuser $ftppass
      binary
      cd $putdir
     delete ${lista[`expr $FNO+8`]}
     quit
 EOMYF2

   fi
 fi
  (( FNO = $FNO + 9 ))
done
```

Please need help with this.

---

Thanks, for trying to help me. Yes, I copied it from pastebin itself. When i tried with ls *.txt  getting output as below it is not getting $5 value hence, per your suggession tried ls -l *.txt. what else can I try?

- set -- ccc_20160301.txt
- (( 1 > 9 ))
- [[  == Feb ]]
- read line

Below is the script I have copied from pastebin itself

```
#!/bin/ksh -px
# get a list of files and dates from ftp and remove files older than ndays

ftpsite="ftp.com"
ftpuser="ftpuser"
ftppass="ftppass"
putdir="/xxx/yyy"



MM=$(TZ=GMT+29 date +%b)
DD=$(TZ=GMT+29 date +%d)

echo "removing files older than $MM $DD"

 # get directory listing from remote source
echo "
user $ftpuser $ftppass
binary
cd $putdir
ls *.txt
quit" | ftp -i -n $ftpsite | while read line; do
    # line is *each line*, rather than a list of everything
    # helps if the filenames have spaces. Just chomp into $0..
    set -- $line
    # month (element 5), day (element 6) and filename (element 8)
    if (($# > 9)); then
        echo "Can't deal with '$@'"
        continue
    fi
    # check the date stamp
    if [[ $5 == "$MM" ]];
   then
        if (($6 < $DD ));
        then
            # Remove this file
            filename=$8
            echo "Removing $filename"

            # replace the ftp with cat with ftp $ftpsite
            cat <<EOMYF2
            ftp -n -i $ftpsite
            user $ftpuser $ftppass
            binary
            cd $putdir
            delete $filename
            quit
EOMYF2
       fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign: `lista=$listing`, it's a simple variable assignment.

You want to assign `listing` to `lista` as an array. The syntax for that is:

```
set -A lista $listing
```

> BTW, I'd use `$()` instead of backticks for command invocation, and use `$((math))` instead of `expr math`, as they're more ksh-fluent.

Trying to debug the ftp list of files:

```
ftpsite="xxx.com"
ftpuser="ftpuser"
ftppass="ftppwd"
putdir="/ftpdir"

ftp -i -n $ftpsite <<EOM
user $ftpuser $ftppass
binary
cd $putdir
ls -l *.txt
quit
EOM
```

this will list all the files that are considered - you need to ensure that they all are of the same format.

Once you've ensured that the format is compliant with the expected 9 items per line, then you can attempt to debug the script.

Comment: Thanks, for responding. 
I changed this lista=($listing)  
but, now getting this 0403-057 Syntax error at line 50 : `(' is not expected.

Comment: Is there a leading space before the `EOMYF2` on the line closing the here document? If there is, then remove it - here document code closes on finding the end word at the start of the line. Additionally the less than test needs to be unquoted, and use `<` rather than `-lt`. I'd feed the code to [`shellcheck.net`](http://shellcheck.net) for a complete list of warnings/suggestions.

Comment: Using shellcheck.net fixed all the issues. But, still getting error at this line lista=($listing) which states 0403-057 Syntax error at line ... : `(' is not expected.

Comment: ok, you're on AIX? you may need to explicitly do `typeset -a lista=($listing)` in that case - the automatic variable typing is probably not happening in that case.

Comment: Tried typeset -a lista=($listing) still getting same error. Thanks, for trying to help me.

Comment: You may need it on two lines: `set -a lista` followed by `lista=($listing)`, it may not support declaring and initializing on the same line.

Comment: Tried set -a lista followed by lista=($listing) as well getting same error. Yes, I am using AIX.

Comment: my bad - slightly different set syntax - `set -A lista $listing` should have the desired effect, instead of the two lines

Comment: Thank you. That fixed that issue.

But, if I use "ls -l" I am getting this error
-rw-r--r--: 0403-010 A specified flag is not valid for this command.

If I use just "ls" then if ((${lista[$((FNO + 5))]} == MM )); is failing
${lista[$((FNO + 5))]} has the file name and MM is the month Feb. 
I tried changing the FNO + 5 to FNO + 4 and FNO + 6 it is just getting the before after file names
what am I missing?

Comment: Look at the data returned from the `ls -l` output - your parsing expects 9 items returned per-line and it sounds like one or more of them doesn't have 9 items per line

Comment: listing=$(ftp -nv <<EOMYF 
    open ftp.com
    user ftpuser ftppass
    
    
    cd /xxx/yyy
    ls -l *.txt
    quit
    EOMYF
   )

 
    set -A lista $listing

Variable listing/lista are having values of the output of trying to connect to ftp site and ls -l *txt of the current dir not the files from ftp site. How to make the variable listing/lista to have the ls -l *txt of ftp server?

Comment: the `-v` option is causing the interactive output to end up in `$listing` - you don't want it for the result of the ftp command, so you should remove it. You should test the command in a small stand-alone script until you get the syntax of the command and response correct. When I use this command: http://pastebin.com/vbSQTHWU - the result of `echo "$capture"` only contains the output of the directory listing.

Comment: This is a rewrite without using arrays, in a line-oriented fashion which is probably slightly easier to read and understand - http://pastebin.com/X5pSWd4e - we're well beyond trying to debug the original issue at this point.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. looks like , this is failing still $5 is no



if [[ $5 == "$MM" ]];
    then
        if (($6 < $DD )); 




+ set -- xxx_20160224.txt
+ (( 1 > 9 ))
+ [[  == Feb ]]
+ read line
+ set -- yyy_20160225.txt
+ (( 1 > 9 ))
+ [[  == Feb ]]
+ read line
+ set -- zzz_20160226.txt
+ (( 1 > 9 ))
+ [[  == Feb ]]
+ read line

Comment: Need help with this please

Comment: Ok, in this case it looks like the behaviour of the remote server is that `ls` produces short-form output (the file name only). As a result, I'd put the `-l` back into the `ls` command to get it to give the full line output.

Comment: Tried this
.......

+ echo removing files older than Feb 28
removing files older than Feb 28
+ echo
user ftpuser ftppass
binary
cd /xxx/yyy
ls -l *.txt
quit
+ ftp -i -n ftp.com
+ read line
$

After read line I see nothing now.

Comment: any suggestions please.

Comment: Do the files exist any more? Have you tried running the ftp command interactively to see what appears? At this point there is nothing left for me to do here - I've tried to address all the technical issues with the script; but by this point, I don't even know what script you're running; etc. based on the `+` output, you may be running the last pastebin I put in (with the change from `ls *.txt` -> `ls -l *.txt`), but I just don't know.